# sugerencia con mi codigo de eliminacion de atributo

Tags: python

Una consulta como puedo definir bien la funcion def eliminar(): de mi programa(codigo), quisiera eliminar  todos los atributos guardados cuando uso la funcion de registrar. El programa si corre, puedo registrar y las funciones de registro, monstrar y buscar estan funcionando con normalidad , pero no consigo eliminar los atributos que mi programa guarda, Alguien me puede sugerir como puedo modificar el codigo de la funcion def eliminar para eliminar los objetos guardados?

```
import os

RP=1
CP=2
ED=3
LR=4
EP=5
Sal=6

lista=list()

class Personas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nID=( )
        self.nombre=(" ")
        self.edad=( )
        self.profesion=(" ")


def monstrar_menu():
    print(f'''   menu presentado
    {RP}) Registrar personal
    {CP}) Consultar personal
    {ED}) Editar datos del personal
    {LR}) Listar personal registrado
    {EP}) Eliminar personal
    {Sal}) Salir
        ''')

def registrar():
    persona=Personas()
    print()
    persona.nID=int(input("introduce el nuevo nID del personal: "))
    persona.nombre = input("introduce el nuevo nombre del personal: ")
    persona.edad = input("introduce la nueva edad del personal: ")
    persona.profesion= input("introduce la nueva profesion del personal: ")
    lista.append(persona)

def monstrar():

    for persona in lista:
        print("El nID del personal es ", persona.nID, " ,su nombre es ", persona.nombre, ", su edad es " , persona.edad, " , y su profesion es " , persona.profesion)

def buscar():
    print("Sistema de busqueda por nID del personal")
    nID1=int(input("Ingrese el nID del personal buscado: "))
    for persona in lista:
        if persona.nID == nID1:
            print("Los datos de la persona consultada con el nID ", persona.nID, "son nombre: "  ,persona.nombre, " ,edad: " , persona.edad , " ,profesion: " , persona.profesion)

def eliminar():
    print("Sistema de eliminacion por nID del personal")
    nID = input("Ingrese el nID del personal que desea eliminar: ")
    for i in range(len(nID)-1,-1,-1):
        if nID[i] == nID:
            nID.pop(i)
            nombre.pop(i)
            edad.pop(i)
            profesion.pop(i)

    print("Se elimino el personal deseado")

continuar= True
while continuar:
    os.system("cls")
    monstrar_menu()
    opc=int(input("Seleccione un numero por favor: "))
    if opc == RP:
        os.system("cls")
        print ("Sistema de registro del Personal")
        print()
        registrar()


    elif opc == CP:
        os.system("cls")
        print("Sistema de busqueda por nID del personal")
        buscar()

    elif opc == ED:
        os.system("cls")
        print("Sistema de edicion de registros del personal")


    elif opc == LR:
        os.system("cls")
        print("Sistema de Visualizacion de datos del personal")
        monstrar()

    elif opc == EP:
        os.system("cls")
        print("Sistema de eliminacion de datos del personal")
        eliminar()

    elif opc == Sal:
        continuar = False
    else:
        print("Gracias por usar el sistema, que tenga un buen dia")
```

He probado tambien con la funcion del algo asi del (persona.nID, persona.nombre, persona.edad, persona.profesion), pero no ha funcionado, alguien me puede sugerir una forma de resolverlo?

Comment: decir que no te ha funcionado no es de ayuda. Debes describir el problema. Has probado con `del lista[i]` donde `i` es la posición del objeto que deseas eliminar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

En la función `eliminar()` podrías iterar directamente la lista de personas que ya tienes en lugar de crear un nuevo rango, lo importante para poder eliminar un objeto tipo `Personas` de tu lista es primero obtener el índice del objeto dentro de la lista y el objeto `Personas` para poder hacer tu comparación del `nID` que el usuario desea eliminar

Para poder obtener tanto el índice como el objeto puedes utilizar `enumerate()` de la siguiente forma

```
for i, persona in enumerate(lista):
```

Esto te va a devolver el índice en la variable `i` y el objeto en la variable `persona`

Para eliminar el objeto de tu lista puedes utilizar `del lista[i]`

Hay otro problema en la función `eliminar()` ya que el `input()` obtiene un `string` en tu línea `nID = input("Ingrese el nID del personal que desea eliminar: ")` pero tu objeto `Personas` tiene un `int` ya que así lo programaste en la línea `persona.nID=int(input("introduce el nuevo nID del personal: "))` de la función `registrar()` por lo que si sólo se compara `if persona.nID == nID:` adentro del `for` en tu función `eliminar()` el resultado va a ser siempre `False` y por lo tanto las acciones dentro del `if` nunca se ejecutarían

El código completo con todas las correcciones mencionadas anteriormente para la función `eliminar()` sería:

```
def eliminar():
    print("Sistema de eliminacion por nID del personal")
    nID = int(input("Ingrese el nID del personal que desea eliminar: "))
    for i, persona in enumerate(lista):
      if persona.nID == nID:
        del lista[i]

    print("Se elimino el personal deseado")
```

Otra observación, cuando registras edad no estás solicitando `int` por lo que es posible poner cualquier caracter

```
persona.edad = input("introduce la nueva edad del personal: ")
```

Esto no es parte de tu pregunta pero es un punto que debes considerar. Cada vez que utilices `input()` deberías agregar validación de datos de entrada porque tu código como está actualmente si ingresas por ejemplo una letra en `persona.nID` al registrar entonces solo te mandaría error pero en un programa real para un usuario no deberían aparecer esos errores, deberías indicarle al usuario que el valor ingresado no es correcto y que debe ingresar solo números

Actualmente si ingresas una letra en `persona.nID` te devuelve este error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Y estos errores los debes evitar ya que hacen que tu programa sea terminado e impiden al usuario trabajar con el software

Un ejemplo sencillo de validación sería:

```
def inputNum(prompt):
  while True:
    try:
      value = int(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
      print("El valor ingresado debe ser numérico y sin decimales.")
      continue

    if value < 0:
      print("El valor ingresado no puede ser negativo.")
      continue
    else:
      break
  return value
```

Y lo puedes utilizar en tu función `registrar()` de la siguiente forma:

```
def registrar():
    persona=Personas()
    print()
    persona.nID= inputNum("introduce el nuevo nID del personal: ")
    persona.nombre = input("introduce el nuevo nombre del personal: ")
    persona.edad = inputNum("introduce la nueva edad del personal: ")
    persona.profesion= input("introduce la nueva profesion del personal: ")
    lista.append(persona)
```

Conclusión, en un programa real que va a ser utilizado por usuarios no debería haber errores que terminen tu programa inesperadamente. Debes guiar al usuario a ingresar el tipo de datos y en el rango que el programa espera recibir, para eso sirve la validación de datos de entrada

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu comentario, como recien estoy comenzando aun no me parece tan evidente a la hora de programar. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ayudaste mucho